# Visual Studio 2017 and WinJS - Autocomplete for "Windows" namespace

Tags: javascript, uwp, visual-studio-2017, winjs

I'm writing a UWP windows 10 app with html/javascript in VS 2017. When I used to write Windows8 apps in VS 2015, the "Windows" namespace would autocomplete for me, intellisense and all that, but now it's not.

For example, if I have `var vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();`, I don't get any autocomlete options with `vault.`, but I would have on VS2015.

What's going wrong? How can I add whatever files necessary to my project to get the intellisense working for this?

Comment: It's better to post an answer directly instead of edit your question.

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it was because Resharper was hiding some intellisense from me. When I turn it off I get the Windows apis back.